# Is a judge required to explain his ruling?

Tags: civil-law, landlord, civil-procedure, court, new-jersey

A friend of mine was recently in Special Civil court where the Defendant submitted a 25 page motion to dismiss the case.

The judge read the motion (to himself, quietly) and announced that he does not agree with the motion. He gave less than a two minute explanation - addressing only a small fraction of the arguments raised in the motion and then proceeded to discuss the actual case.

Is a judge required to go through each argument separately and explain why it isn't valid? Is the party who filed the motion entitled to a clear and thorough understanding as to what grounds the motion is being rejected?

If the party who filed the motion isn't aware on what grounds the judge dismissed the motion, how can they file an appeal?

Comment: Rues for such things vary by jurisdiction, in particular by country, but within the US might vary by state. Do you have a particular jurisdiction in mind?

Comment: @DavidSiegel NJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denial of a motion to dismiss is not an appealable order. Likewise, denial of a motion for summary judgment cannot be appealed except in rare cases where it deals with a privilege against being sued like qualified or absolute immunity from suit.

If an order can be appealed, it can be reversed on appeal if the trial court did not provide an adequate basis to justify its ruling.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your insight. Said motion was filed as a motion to dismiss the case and compel arbitration. In [a recent question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87185/filling-a-complaint-to-compel-arbitration) I discuss the option of filing  a **complaint** to compel arbitration instead of a motion to compel. I raised the question of whether there is any legal benefit to using one venue over the other (motion vs. complaint). Based on the response you provided here...

Comment: ..it seems like a natural conclusion that filing a complaint to compel arbitration provides at least one practical legal benefit - which is that if the complaint is dismissed it can be appealed and the party filling the complaint is entitled to receive a clear explanation as to why it was rejected? Would you concur?

Comment: @S.O.S. If a court compels arbitration, due to a special arbitration specific rule not followed in other kinds of cases, that ruling can't be appealed until the arbitration is completed.

Comment: @ _ohwilleke thanks for your reply. In this example, the court **dismissed** the motion to compel arbitration without providing a thorough explanation. My question is if it were filed as a complaint to compel arbitration instead of a motion and the complaint was dismissed, would the dismissal of the **complaint** (to compel arbitration) be appealable? Or there is no distinction between the two (both are not appealable)?

Comment: @S.O.S. the Washington State statue which is typical of the Uniform Act is here: https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=7.04A.280 (1) An appeal may be taken from:
(a) An order denying a motion to compel arbitration;
(b) An order granting a motion to stay arbitration;
(c) An order confirming or denying confirmation of an award;
(d) An order modifying or correcting an award;
(e) An order vacating an award without directing a rehearing; or
(f) A final judgment entered under this chapter.
(2) An appeal under this section must be taken as from an order or a judgment in a civil action.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I'm sorry if this is obvious but "an appeal may be taken from" means that the order **is** appealable or that it is not appealable? It sounds like (from your other comment) that arbitration is the exception to the general rule and an order to dismiss a motion to compel arbitration is appealable (even though other kinds of motions are not) Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @S.O.S.  "an appeal may be taken from" means that the order is appealable. the rules on when arbitration rulings may be appealed are an exception to the general rule.

Comment: @ _ohwilleke If this is the case then logically the judge should be required to thoroughly debunk each argument in a motion to compel arbitration and if the judge fails to do so this would be grounds to appeal the motion?

Comment: @S.O.S. Perhaps, but the appeal comes much later and it is very common for a ruling on a motion to not address every issue at length. Often one argument alone is sufficient to decide the matter. Judges have hundreds or thousands of cases each year to rule upon and late or incomplete rulings are common.